# SearchVectorField - joined reference not allowed for taggit field

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-taggit

My model definition is as follows (a simplified model of the one being used in actual product. There are a coupe of other fields:

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVectorField
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import GinIndex

class Product(models.Model):
    tags = TaggableManager()
    search_vector = SearchVectorField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            GinIndex(fields=['search_vector'])
        ]
```

I run make migrations and migrate commands. These work correctly.

I then run the following set of commands to build the index:

```
search_vector = SearchVector('tags__name')
Product.objects.all().update(search_vector=search_vector)
```

I end up getting the following error:

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Joined field references are not permitted in this query`

This is clearly caused by the `tags__name` field, but I am not sure how to solve it.

Can someone please explain what I would need to do in order to run the above commands correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot be done this way.

A possible approach is to write custom triggers using self-made migration. Triggers would look into table `tag` and update the index `search_vector` on each action of these:

- INSERT into `product`,
- INSERT into `tag`,
- UPDATE `tag`,
- DELETE from `tag`,
- Updating `Product`'s tags.

Looks like a real mess? So it is. [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154011/postgresql-full-text-search-tsv-column-trigger-with-many-to-many) you can see one guy tried this approach.

I'd suggest a more straightforward way. You can add `product.tags_for_search` `TextField`, which would be maintained manually.

- Let's refuse the deletion of tags. They can be marked `DELETED`, so we wouldn't need to update `product.tags_for_search` when a tag is deleted.
- If we need to rename a tag and remain all the relations, we just can add one and copy all the relations.
- For inserting entries of `product` everything is fine, you just need to set a proper field value, same goes for updating a set of tags.

Your goal seems quite achievable for me this way.